# pyspark AnalysisException: "Reference '<COLUMN>' is ambiguous

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to list the column in a dataframe but i am getting an ambiguous column error.

```
$df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ACTION: string (nullable = true)

$df_new.select(["ACTION"]).show()
AnalysisException: "Reference 'ACTION' is ambiguous, could be: ACTION#22058, ACTION#22334
```

Comment: Where's `df_new`'s schema? Is it a product of a self-join or of a join that duplicated column names?

Comment: Your df_new has 2 columns named ACTION